# Does John 3:36 mean that those preceding Jesus will “not see life” as a result?

Tags: john, new-testament, soteriology

John 3:36 KJV

> He that believeth on the Son hath everlasting life: and he that believeth not the Son shall not see life; but the wrath of God abideth on him.

Based on this verse, how were people in Old Testament times able to receive eternal life if at all?

Comment: If you edited this to say "Does John mean that all OT people will 'not see life' because they didn't believe in the son?" I think that would be on-topic and I'd reopen it.

Comment: @RHPclass79... are you open to curiousdanni's suggestion to edit your question so that it reads "Does John mean that all OT people will 'not see life'?" Unfortunately my draft answer is lost now but I'd still like to address the issue. One of my main points would have been that "salvation" in the OT is a different thing than in the NT. In fact the term "eternal life" does not appear in the OT. I agree with NigelJ's comment at the beginning of this thread.

Comment: In answer to your question of editing it really makes little sense with the edit. Jesus was prophesied in the Old Testament as the coming messiah in many verses but until the shedding of blood there was no remission of sins. The whole new testament rest on Jesus and his death on the cross and then our believing on him period

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149994/discussion-on-question-by-rhpclass79-how-could-people-in-old-testament-receive-e); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @ curiousdaannii. I have racked my brain on how to reword this so as to pass rules. The reason that I could not except your edit was because you said all people. We know some were taken up to heaven. Ex. Enoch and Elijah. Moses on the MT. Of transfiguration. So my question a dressing that particular new testament verse can only be harmonized if some did know Jesus in some way. I repeat that Jesus was not available to old Testament people. He had not been born of a virgin at that time. I have taught for years that he made guest appearances as the Lord or Angel of.TBCont.

Comment: How to make this fit your rules I am not sure, but I know it is a great ?. I saw your edit or mod. on Rev. 9 years ago. Your description of both sides of the 7 sealed scroll being 2 simultaneous happenings was very plausible. If you could tie that scripturally to Ezekiel's scroll that is written on both sides that 2 simultaneous prophecies actually happened that would be great proof for your theory. Bear in mind that Ezekiel was prophesying events that happened 2600 years ago. After Ch. 40 is future to us so don't go that far.  Later!